# What do you call a "chunk" of a circle

Tags: geometry, terminology, circles

Like, what do you call a third of a circle, or a quarter of a circle

Comment: Like a pizza slice? It's called a sector.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle

Comment: @JoshuaWang if you are referring to the difference of two circular segments, for example $\{(x,y)~:~x^2+y^2\leq 1,~0.5\leq y\leq 0.6\}$, I often hear that referred to instead as a "slice."

Comment: A third of a *circle* or third of a *disk*?  If *circle*:  "arc."  If *disk*:  "sector."

Comment: @DavidG.Stork In practice, I don't think people draw a distinction between a circle and a disk. We often speak of the 'area of a circle'.

Answer (score 3):

A [circular sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector). The larger 'chunk' is called the major sector and the smaller chunk the minor sector.

[image: Circle sector]